Telebot, beautifulsoup4. Как вернуть 2 и более значений из функции в send_message
Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял сразу два (или более) результата парсинга (ответа функции). Допустим, хочу спарсить температуру и осадки.
def pars(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(html).text, 'lxml')
    temperature = soup.find('span', class_="_h3 align-top me-1 d-inline-block")
    weather = soup.find('div', class_="col-16 text-500")
    #print(weather, temperature)
    #data = {temperature, weather }
    return temperature, weather
    
  <...>

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=pars(url))  

При таком коде в телеграме мне приходит только что-то одно. При попытке вернуть data на один город упорно присылает только температуру, на другой - погоду.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в одном сообщении поместить несколько переменных?

Форматировать значения в строку.

return f"Погода: {temperature}, {weather}"

Действительно, сработало, но получился вывод вида: Погода: <span class="_h3 align-top me-1 d-inline-block">+6°</span>, <div class="col-16 text-500">облачно</div>, пришлось приписать .text: return f"Погода: {temperature.text}, {weather.text}"

Мне интересно, есть ли еще какие-то способы? Изучаю telebot всего 1 день :D Может, стоит еще погуглить, но вдруг кто-то знает ответ

Это оптимальное и правильное решение в данной ситуации. Зачем искать другие способы?

Понял, принял) Спасибо!

Обычно несколько значений можно вернуть как тупл return a, b и принять a, b = f().
Но да, этот пример строкой удобнее.

Спасибо решениям в комментариях под вопросом!
Несколько значений нужно возвращать в виде форматированной строки
return f"Погода: {temperature.text}, {weather.text}"
